# Is there a way to send Quick Replies back from Fulfillment Webhook?

Tags: javascript, bots, dialogflow-es

I have been playing around with DialogFlow and Fulfillment but until now I have always returned FulfillmentText from my webhook back to my bot like this:

```
response = {
    fulfillmentText: "Some message!"
};
```

Is there any way to return a set of options here (quick replies) instead? Basically I want to return 3 buttons, one for each of option a, b, and c. Is this possible?

Thanks!

### EDIT:

I was able to send a card back using the following code but I can't find any samples which send back quick replies rather than a card.

```
"fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "card": {
        "title": "card title",
        "subtitle": "card text",
        "imageUri": "https://assistant.google.com/static/images/molecule/Molecule-Formation-stop.png",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "text": "button text",
            "postback": "https://assistant.google.com/"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Rich UI Messages](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages) from Dialogflow. Depending on the platform you are developing, you can show quick replies or cards or other Rich UI messages. 
On Web and Mobile apps (Native) you will need to handle them on your own by passing a flag as to what you want (button, check box, etc) and manipulate the text response.

**UPDATE**
If using Google Assistant, you may follow following link https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses

It would be better to use Client Libraries for developing Webhooks
[Action-On-Google NodeJS Client](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs)
[Dialogflow NodeJS Fulfillment Client](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs)

Comment: Thanks! I am able to set up the quick replies from the DialogFlow UI fine but is there any way for me to send the quick reply options in my webhook's response?

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile but this little shortcut worked for me on Facebook Messenger Platform if someone is still looking for this.

```
const {Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
agent.add(new Suggestion('Suggestion'));
```

Answer (score 1):

heres an example:

```
fulfillmentMessages: [
    {
        quickReplies: {
            title: 'Hello',
            quickReplies: [
                'First Reply',
                'Second Reply',
            ],
        },
        platform: 'FACEBOOK'
     },
};
```

Also, heres the trick :) https://miningbusinessdata.com/how-to-send-any-facebook-messenger-rich-response-from-dialogflow-webhook/

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem myself. Generally, the problem is that the creator of card-response.js didn't predict that anyone would want to make quick replies as a card button. Replace the code in the dialogflow-fulfillment/src/rich-response/card-response.js with the code below. I just added exceptions that support the absence of buttonsUrl.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
const {
  RichResponse,
  PLATFORMS,
  SUPPORTED_RICH_MESSAGE_PLATFORMS,
  V2_TO_V1_PLATFORM_NAME,
} = require('./rich-response');

/**
 * Enum for Dialogflow v1 text message object https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/message-objects
 */
const v1MessageObjectCard = 1;

/**
 * Class representing a card response
 * @extends RichResponse
 */
class Card extends RichResponse {
  /**
   * Constructor for Card object.
   *
   * @example
   *
   * @param {string|Object} card response title string or an object representing a card response
   */
  constructor(card) {
    super();
    if (card === undefined || (typeof card === 'object' && !card.title)) {
      throw new Error('title string required by Card constructor');
    }
    if (typeof card === 'string') {
      this.title = card;
    } else if (typeof card === 'object') {
      this.title = card.title;
      this.text = card.text;
      this.imageUrl = card.imageUrl;
      if(card.buttonUrl) {
        this.buttonUrl = card.buttonUrl;
      }
      if(!card.buttonUrl) {
        card.buttonUrl = "buffor"
      }
      if (
        (!card.buttonText && card.buttonUrl) ||
        (!card.buttonUrl && card.buttonText)
      ) {
        throw new Error('card button requires title or title with link');
      }
      this.buttonText = card.buttonText;
      if (
        typeof card.platform !== 'undefined' &&
        card.platform !== PLATFORMS.UNSPECIFIED
      ) {
        if (SUPPORTED_RICH_MESSAGE_PLATFORMS.indexOf(card.platform) < 0) {
          throw new Error(`Platform '${card.platform}' not supported.`);
        } else {
          this.platform = card.platform;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Set the title for a Card
   *
   * @example
   * let card = new Card();
   * card.setTitle('sample card title')
   *
   * @param {string} title containing the title content
   * @return {Card}
   */
  setTitle(title) {
    if (typeof title !== 'string') {
      throw new Error('setText requires a string of the text');
    }
    this.title = title;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Set the text for a Card
   *
   * @example
   * let card = new Card();
   * card.setText('sample card body text')
   *
   * @param {string} text containing the card body text content
   * @return {Card}
   */
  setText(text) {
    if (typeof text !== 'string') {
      throw new Error('setText requires a string of the text');
    }
    this.text = text;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Set the image for a Card
   *
   * @example
   *
   * @param {string} imageUrl
   * @return {Card}
   */
  setImage(imageUrl) {
    if (typeof imageUrl !== 'string') {
      throw new Error('setImage requires a string of the image URL');
    }
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Set the button for a Card
   *
   * @example
   * let card = new Card();
   * card.setButton({
   *     text: 'button text',
   *     url: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
   * });
   *
   * @param {Object} button JSON configuration
   * @param {Object} options.text button text
   * @param {Object} options.url button link URL
   * @return {Card}
   */
  setButton(button) {
    if ((!button.text)) {
      throw new Error(
        `card button requires button title and url. \
\nUsage: setButton({text: \'button text\', url: \'http://yoururlhere.com\'}`
      );
    }
    this.buttonText = button.text;
    if(button.url) {
      this.buttonUrl = button.url;
    }
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get the v1 response object for the rich response
   * https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/message-objects
   *
   * @example
   * let richResponse = new RichResponse();
   * richResponse.getV1ResponseObject_(PLATFORMS.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE)
   *
   * @param {string} platform desired message object platform
   * @return {Object} v1 response object
   * @private
   */
  getV1ResponseObject_(platform) {
    // Check if response is platform specific
    if (this.platform && this.platform !== platform) {
      // if it is and is not for the specific platform return null
      return null;
    }

    //
    let response;
    if (platform === PLATFORMS.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE) {
      // If the platform is Actions on Google use a simple response
      response = {
        type: 'basic_card',
        platform: V2_TO_V1_PLATFORM_NAME[platform],
      };
      response.title = this.title;
      if (!this.text && !this.imageUrl) {
        response.formattedText = ' '; // AoG requires text or image in card
      }
      if (this.text) response.formattedText = this.text;
      if (this.imageUrl) {
        response.image = {};
        response.image.url = this.imageUrl;
        response.image.accessibilityText = 'accessibility text';
      }

      if (this.buttonText) {
        response.buttons = [{openUrlAction: {}}];
        response.buttons[0].title = this.buttonText;
        if(this.buttonUrl) {
          response.buttons[0].openUrlAction.url = this.buttonUrl;
        }
      }
    } else {
      response = {type: v1MessageObjectCard};
      response.title = this.title;
      if (this.text) response.subtitle = this.text;
      if (this.imageUrl) response.imageUrl = this.imageUrl;
      // this is required in the response even if there are no buttons for some reason
      if (platform === PLATFORMS.SLACK) response.buttons = [];
      if (this.buttonText && this.buttonUrl) {
        response.buttons = [];
        response.buttons[0] = {};
        response.buttons[0].text = this.buttonText;
        if(this.buttonUrl) {
          response.buttons[0].postback = this.buttonUrl;
        }
      }
      // response is the same for generic responses without the platform attribute
      // if the platform is not undefined or the platform is not unspecified
      if (SUPPORTED_RICH_MESSAGE_PLATFORMS.indexOf(platform) > -1) {
        response.platform = V2_TO_V1_PLATFORM_NAME[platform];
      }
    }
    return response;
  }

  /**
   * Get the v2 response object for the rich response
   * https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#Message
   *
   * @example
   * let richResponse = new RichResponse();
   * richResponse.getV2ResponseObject_(PLATFORMS.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE)
   *
   * @param {string} platform desired message object platform
   * @return {Object} v2 response object
   * @private
   */
  getV2ResponseObject_(platform) {
    // Check if response is platform specific
    if (this.platform && this.platform !== platform) {
      // if it is and is not for the specific platform return null
      return null;
    }

    let response;
    if (platform === PLATFORMS.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE) {
      // If the platform is Actions on Google use a basic card response
      response = {basicCard: {}};
      response.basicCard.title = this.title;
      response.platform = PLATFORMS.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE;
      if (this.text) response.basicCard.formattedText = this.text;
      if (this.imageUrl) {
        response.basicCard.image = {};
        response.basicCard.image.imageUri = this.imageUrl;
        response.basicCard.image.accessibilityText = 'accessibility text';
      }
      if (this.buttonText && !this.buttonUrl) {
        response.basicCard.buttons = [{
          title: this.buttonText
        }];
      }
      if (this.buttonText && this.buttonUrl) {
        response.basicCard.buttons = [{
          title: this.buttonText,
          openUriAction: {
            uri: this.buttonUrl,
          },
        }];
      }
    } else {
      response = {card: {}};
      response.card.title = this.title;
      if (this.text) response.card.subtitle = this.text;
      if (this.imageUrl) response.card.imageUri = this.imageUrl;
      if (this.buttonText && !this.buttonUrl) {
        response.card.buttons = [];
        response.card.buttons[0] = {};
        response.card.buttons[0].text = this.buttonText;
      }
      if (this.buttonText && this.buttonUrl) {
        response.card.buttons = [];
        response.card.buttons[0] = {};
        response.card.buttons[0].text = this.buttonText;
        response.card.buttons[0].postback = this.buttonUrl;
      }
      // response is the same for generic responses without the platform attribute
      // if the platform is not undefined or the platform is not unspecified
      if (SUPPORTED_RICH_MESSAGE_PLATFORMS.indexOf(platform) > -1) {
        response.platform = platform;
      }
    }
    return response;
  }
}

module.exports = Card;
```